# Microsoft Ribbon for WPF, RibbonButton LargeImage only

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ribbon

if the RibbonButton contains no Label there is a lot of free space under the LargeImage icon. Instead of using a text, i would like to enlarge the image (width and height).
However, i didn't found a solution to do that.

The only thing i found out is to configure a margin in order to place the Image in the center, but I want the image to be streched to fit the whole region.

Any comments on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the Template (use Blend or if if you don't have blend do it this way: [.NET 4 control default templates without Blend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143698/net-4-control-default-templates-without-blend))

This is the default control template part of the ribbon button style:

```
  <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ribbon:RibbonButton}">
    <Border x:Name="OuterBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
      <Border x:Name="InnerBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
        <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanel">
          <Image x:Name="PART_Image" 
                 RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                 Height="32" Margin="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=LargeImageMargin, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type ribbon:Ribbon}}}" Source="{TemplateBinding LargeImageSource}" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                 Width="32"/>
          <Grid x:Name="Grid" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ribbon:RibbonTwoLineText x:Name="TwoLineText" HorizontalAlignment="Center" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" LineHeight="13" Margin="1,1,1,0" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{TemplateBinding Label}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
          </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
      </Border>
    </Border>
```

Change this to your needs, you could for example adjust the width and height of the image to the surrounding Border:

```
 <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ribbon:RibbonButton}">
    <Border x:Name="OuterBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
      <Border x:Name="InnerBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
        <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanel">
          <Image x:Name="PART_Image" 
                 RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                 Stretch="Fill" Height="{Binding ElementName=InnerBorder, Path=ActualHeight}"
                 Margin="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=LargeImageMargin, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type ribbon:Ribbon}}}" Source="{TemplateBinding LargeImageSource}" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                 />
          <Grid x:Name="Grid" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ribbon:RibbonTwoLineText x:Name="TwoLineText" HorizontalAlignment="Center" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" LineHeight="13" Margin="1,1,1,0" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{TemplateBinding Label}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
          </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
```

Comment: so, i tried to place the <ControlTemplate x:Key="temp"...> within  <Window.Resources> and added the Template to the RibbonButton.
The Image is now large, however ther is no more hover effekt available. 

Do I have to do smthng additional?

Comment: Theres alot more code in the ControlTemplate than the code above. My snippet is just an excerpt.
If you use the complete control template the IsmouseOver/Hoover should work fine.
So use the above way with blend or the link to get the complete default control template. I'm sorry I can't post it here as it is too large and I don't want to mess this thread...

Comment: i got it, thanks. now i did extract the whole template and now everything works. thanks for the support sven!